# Video is not opening in iOS 8 beta UIWebView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview, ios8

I am Opening a Video in UIWebView by URL and it is working fine in other Os while in iOS 8 it is showing only play symbol but not playing.

I know this question is new as beta has just launched, but if please help if anyone has idea regarding this.

Thanks

Comment: As always: https://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: Can you give an example of a URL that does this

Comment: Any update on this? I also have this issue on the latest beta.

Answer (score 1):

I am seeing the same thing. Same code worked fine on iOS 7, but as soon as I upgraded to iOS 8, when I press the play button, it switches to the Pause icon, but does not play... I logged a bug with Apple, and it is currently marked as an OPEN duplicate, so I'm thinking that means they are aware of the issue.

Comment: I've noticed this in other apps too. Notably Facebook. When you open a webpage (inside the app) that has a video then it doesn't play. When you then "Open in Safari" the video plays fine.